# Sort on subcolumns

Tags: linux, bash

I really need your help on this task. I have the following text file:

```
0001030111
0011030611
0003030113 
0002030112          
0006030311
0004030114       
0007030311
0012030612
```

I want to sort it on the results in the 7th and 8th column in order to get something like that:

```
0001030111
0003030113
0002030112
0004030114
0006030311
0007030311
0011030611
0012030612
      ^^
      Sort by these positions.
```

But using:

sort +0.6 -1.9 -s setup.txt > sorted.txt

i get something that does not appear in the order i'd like. (please see below)

```
0001030111
0002030112
0003030113
0004030114
0007030311
0006030311
0011030611
0012030612
```

Could you please help me with that? Great thanks!!!

Comment: This does not look like a facebook issue. Is that linux or dos command you are using?

Comment: In the result that you get, the values are ordered by the 7th and 8th column (counting from the left).  Do you mean the 7th and 8th column from the right?

Comment: My mistake - don't know how i taget it as facebook in the hurry. Can i change the tag?

Comment: Exactly - i want it from the left - where the possible values are 01,03 and 06 but i can't do that:(

Comment: Is the third list the actual results that you get that aren't what you're expecting? It looks to me like they're correctly sorted on the columns you indicated? Maybe you pasted the wrong output?

Answer (score 0):

To use the obsolete syntax, you may need to set an environment variable to enable it:

```
_POSIX2_VERSION=201112 sort +0.6 -1.9 -s setup.txt > sorted.txt
```

or use the modern syntax:

```
sort -k1.7 -k1.8 -s setup.txt > sorted.txt
```

Comment: Surely you would use `-k1.7,1.8` to sort on the 7th and 8th characters of the first field?

Comment: Great thanks Jonathan!!! With -k1.7,1.8 it worked exactly as i wanted!Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

when sorting using the `0.n` notation,  (without `-k`), recall that the first char in the first column is numbered `0.0`, and that a specification `1.n` implies a second column of data as defined by the field separator value (defualt space char), which can also be set like `-t":"` (not in your example).

So I think the solution to your problem is (using the syntax you're familiar with)

```
sort +0.6 -0.7 -s setup.txt > sorted.txt
#---------^^^^^--- note change here
```

Sorry, but I don't haven any way to test this right now.

I hope this helps.